# Deriving statistics of band limited Random Variable

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables, signal-processing

The question is:

Consider a continuous random number with a Gaussian distribution of mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma$ . The RV is measured from time $t=-\infty$ to $t=\infty$. This time domain signal $x(t)$ is passed through a first order low pass filter with cutoff at *fo*. What would the statistics of the output be? Would it still be Gaussian? If yes, then what is the new mean and variance?

I am unable to understand where to start with this. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: If the RV is Gaussian then it can take negative values. My (limited) understanding of low pass filters is that they apply to frequencies which are always positive. In any case the output will not be Gaussian. Normally a low pass filter will distort the whole spectrum, however if you used an idealized one then the output would be related to a truncated normal distribution https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncated_normal_distribution .

Comment: @user121049Yes the Gaussian can be negative. But the frequency contents come from a Fourier transform of the time domain signal so the negative values are not a problem. I will look at this truncated normal distribution now Thanks.